# Eliminar datos de la sesión si cierro el navegador

Tags: angular

Actualmente los datos de la sesión (token, user) los almaceno en el localStorage, así cuando una sesión abierta y quiero abrir otra pestaña en mi página no tengo problemas. 
Cuestión, necesito que cuando cierro el navegador se borren los datos mencionados, como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Generalmente para eso funciona el token. La lógica sería definir un tiempo corto de vida (30 min)y mientras el usuario este logueado este se renueve cada 25 min. Después de ese tiempo el token se vuelve invalido y por ende tu app te debe redirigir al login. Esto va de la mano con borrar el localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Deberás usar el [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) que tiene exactamente ese fin.

La sesión se mantiene en caso de recarga de la página o reaperturas de ésta. Pero no se mantiene con pestañas nuevas.

En caso de querer mantener esa `sessionStorage` cuando abres una nueva pestaña, deberás asegurarte de compartir el `sessionStorage` a través del `localStorage`.
De este modo tienes un `sessionStorage` *cross-tabs* pero solo para la sesión actual.

Aquí tienes [un artículo](https://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/#:~:text=Right%2C%20sessionStorage%20is%20not%20shared%20across%20tabs.&text=The%20way%20I%20solved%20it,have%20the%20sessionStorage%20for%20us.) que lo explica.

Aquí el ejemplo.

```
if (!sessionStorage.length) {
  // Se lanza el evento storage
  // con la flag 'getSessionStorage'
  localStorage.setItem('getSessionStorage', Date.now());
};

// Este evento se lanza cada vez que hay algún cambio en el
// storage
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {

  // La flag 'getSessionStorage' será el evento que envía
  // una tab para pedir el sessionStorage
  if (event.key == 'getSessionStorage') {

    // Añadimos el sessionStorage actual
    localStorage.setItem('sessionStorage', JSON.stringify(sessionStorage));

    // En este punto se ha ejecutado el evento en la otra tab
    // por lo que ya lo podemos borrar del localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('sessionStorage');

    // Esta es la flag que nos avisa de que se ha enviado el sessionStorage
    // des de la otra tab, por lo que vamos a guardarlo
    // siempre y cuando nuestro sessionStorage esté vacío
  } else if (event.key == 'sessionStorage' && !sessionStorage.length) {

    var data = JSON.parse(event.newValue);

    for (key in data) {
      sessionStorage.setItem(key, data[key]);
    }

    console.log('received from other tab', sessionStorage);

    // Quizás un buen punto para borrar el localStorgae
    // sería aquí, siempre y cuando sepamos que solo habrá una segunda tab.
    // Si hubiesen más, no podemos ganantizar que todas las tabs
    // han obtenido el localStorage. Por eso se borra des del evento `getSessionStorage`.
  }
});
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Ok, gracias, ya pruebo. Iría en el app.component?

Comment: Puedes ponerlo en el `main.js` o con un [`APP_INITIALIZER`](http://www.learn-angular.fr/how-to-call-an-asynchronous-service-before-bootstrap/)